# Render kendo control inside kendo template (Razor)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, templates, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

Is it possible to render a kendo control inside a Kendo Template?
Something like this one?

```
<script id="treeview-template" type="text/kendo-ui-template">  
 @{Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()
 .Name("test")
 .Render();
 }
</script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can, just do not forget to call the **ToClientTemplate** method at the end. This method should be available for any Kendo widget.

Comment: Hi Pechka, could you please tell me how this ToClientTemplate() works? Cant find any documentation about this one. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Pechka! It worked. Ijust removed the "Render()" function. I posted my final solution. :)

Answer (score 8):

Thanks for the help Pechka! **ToClientTemplate()** extension method did the job.

```
<script id="treeview-template" type="text/kendo-ui-template">
         # var ctrlid= item.ControlId; #

         @(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()
         .Name("#=ctrlid#")
         .ToClientTemplate()
         )
</script>
```

But for some reason, when I put "item.ControlId" directly at the name property, it can't render the control.
So i tried storing it in a variable and used that on the name property and it worked. :)